# Java 8 removing an element from List

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am trying to remove an element from a list which has a nested list. Below is my class

```
   class Pets
   private Long id;
   private String categoryName;
  private List<PetCategory> petCategory;
 //setter & getter

   public class PetCategory {
   private String PetCategoryName;
   private String petSymbol;
   private List<PetList> petList;
 //setter & getter
   }

  public class PetList {

  private String petName;
  private String petWithPicture;
  private List<PetAnimalType> petanimaltype;
 //setter & getter
}

public class PetAnimalType {
private String PetAnimalTypeName;
private String PetAnimalId;
private List<String> petbreeds;
```

I am trying to remove an element from List by passing the PetAnimalTypeName. I am getting this PetAnimalTypeName as a list

```
 List<String> checkPetAnimalTypeName=new ArrayList<String>();
 checkPetAnimalTypeName.add("test1");
 checkPetAnimalTypeName.add("test2");

    for(String s1:checkPetAnimalTypeName) {

             m.getpetCategory().stream().filter(x ->
             x.getPetCategoryName().equalsIgnoreCase("somename")) .flatMap(y ->
             y.getPetList().stream()).filter(s ->
              s.getPetName().equalsIgnoreCase("somename")).

             forEach(v->v.getPetanimaltype().removeIf(x1->x1.getPetAnimalTypeName()==s1));

              }
```

It is not removing the element from the List. Could you please help me how to remove the element and better way of echieving this logic

Comment: `x1->x1.getPetAnimalTypeName()==s1`... `equals` instead?

Comment: So silly mistake..Thank you.It worked.

Comment: Any idea?How to get rid of this for(String s1:checkPetAnimalTypeName) {}?Can I process this and compare the list in the stream pipeline??

Comment: it is very hard to tell what you are doing overall, even the `forEach` with side-effects that you have here is wrong

Comment: What is the correct way of doing it? I am trying to remove an element from List<PetAnimalType>. I am getting a new list with String from there I am comparing the existing element in List<PetAnimalType>  and removing the element

Comment: I think one problem here is your strange class design which makes it hard to visualise how to use them and understand what you want to do.

Comment: You can get rid of the for loop: substitute the argument to ```removeIf``` by ```x1 -> checkPetAnimalTypeName.contains(x1.getPetAnimalTypeName())```